# Move Nameserver from crashed BIND servers (DNSSEC Enabled)

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, dnssec

The situation basically is:
The BIND servers that are authoritative for a domain crashed and are utilizing DNSSEC (Ie; I can't change the DNS entries for the zone), is it enough to have the registrar remove the DS entries and then setup the zone in a new name server that does not have DNSSEC enabled?
Obviously, I have to wait out the TTL expiration for the registrar entries to expire before cutting to a new nameserver, but I wasn't sure if there are any major gotchas by just having the registrar do their part and hard cutting to a new, non-DNSSEC zone on a new nameserver.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: why do you not fix the issue with the bind service?